# python 3 как найти координаты области с одинаковыми пикселями если знаю их цвет?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять как найти области с одинаковыми пикселями и получить координаты этих областей?
Пробовал циклами перебирать все пиксели, но выходит слишком долго.

Изображение где требуется искать область с белыми пикселями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получение координат вот этих областей (в рамки выделил для наглядности)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код целиком

````
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from pathlib import Path
from mss import mss
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time


class Object_search:
    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

    def screenshot(self):
        image_1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (0, 0, 1920, 1080))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        image_2 = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (0, 0, 1920, 1080))
        return image_1, image_2

    def comparison(self, image_1, image_2):
        result = ImageChops.difference(image_1, image_2)
        result = result.convert('L')
        result = result.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 1 else 255, '1')
        result.save(r'{}\data\screenshot\screen.png'.format(self.BASE_DIR))
        return result

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('5'):
        print('screenshot')
        image = Object_search().screenshot()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('6'):
        print('comparison')
        comparison = Object_search().comparison(image[0], image[1])
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('8'):
        print('exit')
        time.sleep(0.1)```
````

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался, я бы мог отменить ваш ответ как правильный, если бы вы его оформили)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В OpenCV бы я делал так - слил вместе рассыпавшиеся пикселы объекта с помощью морфологического преобразования замыкания  (`closing = dilation + erosion`).

Затем выделить connected components, для каждого доступен окружающий прямоугольник. Наверное, подобное есть и в PIL